# Number of ways to distribute N items to three peoples under given conditions

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, dynamic-programming

I've been attempting to solve a problem that states, determining the number of ways to distribute N items to three persons. The distribution would consider best if the total weight of items the first person gets is divisible by 3, the weight of items the second person got is divisible by 5 and the total weight of item the last person got is divisible by 7 & the amount of items each person gets should not be 0.

The first input N is considered the number of items & the 2nd line of input denotes N integers representing the weights of items. The i-th integer a[i] denotes the weight of i-th items. There were such constraints as,

```
3≤ N ≤12
1≤ a[i] ≤10^10

sample input 1:
6
2 3 5 7 9 13

sample output 1:
6
```

I tried a way to solve the problem but couldn't figure out how could the solution would be better so that the weight of the items that the first, second & third persons receive would be divisible by 3, 5 & 7 respectively. I tried so that one person gets the maximum amount of items among the three persons & each person gets at least one item, but couldn't figure out the "best" solution that the total weights of items each person gets would be divisible by 3, 5 & 7 respectively.
Could you suggest the solution in DP to solve the problem in all test cases?

Here's my solution to a simple distribution between three people. TIA.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int countWays(int N)
{
    int ans = ((N-1)*(N-2))/2;

    //storing the number of distribution that is not possible
    int s = 0;

    for(int i=2; i<=N-3; i++){
        for(int j=1; j<i; j++){
            //possibilities of 2 persons receiving the maximum
            if (N == 2 * i + j)
                s++;
        }
    }

    if(N%3 == 0)
        s = 3*s+1;
    else
        s = 3*s;

    //final ways to distribute
    return ans - s;
}

int main()
{
    int n, N=0;
    cin >> n;

    if(n<3 && n>12)
        return 0;

    vector<int> a(n);

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        cin>>a[i];
        N += a[i];
    }

    cout<<countWays(N);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dynamic programming state that you need are three flags for whether people 1, 2, and 3 have received anything, followed by 3 numbers giving the sum of what they have received mod 3, 5, and 7.

In Python I'd build up a dictionary whose keys are tuples representing the state and whose values are the counts.  In C++ you might prefer to represent the state as an integer (with each value being encoded by specific bits) and an array to represent the lookup.  Either way you start at the one end with a count 1 for nobody has received anything, process each item and keep track of counts for how they could have been given to each person, and at the other end look up the count for everyone received something and the totals are 0.

Here is a Python solution so you can verify that it makes sense.

```
def divisions (item_weights):
    count_by_state = {(False, 0, False, 0, False, 0): 1}
    for weight in item_weights:
        next_count_by_state = {}

        for state, count in count_by_state.items():
            # Each variable is pX_Y where
            #   X is the person
            #   Y is either r for whether they [r]eceived or w for [w]eight.
            p1_r, p1_w, p2_g, p2_w, p3_g, p3_w= state
            for next_state in [
                (True, (p1_w + weight)%3, p2_g, p2_w, p3_g, p3_w),
                (p1_r, p1_w, True, (p2_w + weight)%5, p3_g, p3_w),
                (p1_r, p1_w, p2_g, p2_w, True, (p3_w + weight)%7),
                ]:
                if next_state in next_count_by_state:
                    next_count_by_state[next_state] += count
                else:
                    next_count_by_state[next_state] = count

        count_by_state = next_count_by_state
    return count_by_state[(True, 0, True, 0, True, 0)]

print(divisions([2, 3, 5, 7, 9, 13]))
```

Note, with more work I could actually print the solutions off in lexicographic order.  With even more I could be asked for, say, the 500th and print just that one.  However that is a dynamic programming trick that I've worked out which none of these competitions seem to think important.

Answer (score 1):

For such small item number you can just generate all items distributions (3^12~~531000) and check for conditions.

```
int countWays(int n, int* arr, int aa = 0, int bb = 0, int cc = 0) {
    if (n < 0) {
        return (aa*bb*cc > 0 && (aa % 3) == 0 && (bb % 5) == 0 && (cc % 7) == 0) ? 1 : 0;
    }
    return countWays(n - 1, arr, aa + arr[n], bb, cc) +
           countWays(n - 1, arr, aa, bb + arr[n], cc) +
           countWays(n - 1, arr, aa, bb, cc + arr[n]);
}

int main()
{
    int n = 6;
    int a[6] = { 2, 3, 5, 7, 9, 13 };

    std::cout << countWays(n-1, a);
}
```

prints `6`

For larger item count perhaps it is worth to use dynamic programming with memoization.

Comment: For given limits program works in millisecond, but DP is much much more complex (at least I suppose for now)

Comment: My raw idea for DP was: for array slice a[0..k-1] make a table with number of sums by modulo 3: 0, 1, 2; by modulo 5: 0..4; by modulo 7: 0..6; and update table using item a[k]. Continue with k+1...

Comment: Did not elaborate. I thought about one table with 105 entries. Also think about meet-in-the-middle principle: calculate such table for the left n/2 items with brute-force like my code, calculate table for the right n/2 items. Multiply counts from both tables for complementary entries and add them. Suitable upto n~30-34

Comment: Dynamic programming shouldn't be very complicated.

Comment: I added a DP solution with code in Python.  It wasn't very complicated.  For fun I threw the first 1000 squares at it and it produced the 475 digit answer in around a third of a second.

Comment: @btilly Nice and concise implementation. I had to extend recursive function arguments with items' presence to see full state and transform to DP in easy way.